# OsTicket dual level filter

Tags: osticket

This is my first question in stack overflow.

I have a problem with OSTicket and its Ticket filter option.

The following is what I set in the filter 1 and filter 2

Filter 1 -- User email contains xxx then set priority to high -- Excecution order 1

Filter 2 -- Priority contains high then SLA plan is 24 hours.

So I raise 2 new tickets as follows

Ticket 1 - user email xxx@yyy.com -- The priority becomes high though I did not make any input in the priority but the system does not do my second check where the filter says if priority is high then SLA should be 24 hrs

Ticket 2 - user email as sidd@yyy.com with priority input as high -- Now the ticket checks for my priority and gives me an SLA plan of 24 hours without my giving an input of SLA plan.

My ticket filter is working fine but the dual level is what is not working. How can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you uncheck "Stop processing further on match!" in filter settings. It is checked by default.